# Regular expression for finding two or more word names separated by spaces in R

Tags: r, regex, parsing

I have a text file that is the output of the `pdf_text()` function from `pdftools`. I'd like to extract names after eache occurance of the label `Name :`. The trouble is that the names themselves are not formatted and may contain two or more words, initials and/or periods, separated by spaces. An example line with the required pattern is shown below:

```
"Name :  O P Bansal   Name :   Ganga Jawar   Name :     Ramachandran G."
```

I would like a list of the form:

```
"O P Bansal"  "Ganga Jawar"  "Ramachandran G."
```

The names have been changed, but they are representative of what I'm working with. There are atleast 5 spaces before the name starts and atleast 10 spaces or a newline after. The individual components of the name itself are separated by a single space or a period followed by a single space (in case of an initial)

Can I express this as a regular expression in R? Something of the form `'Name :\\s+(\\w+\\s)+'`

Answer (score 4):

You may extract them with a single regex:

```
\bName\s*:\s*\K.*?(?=$|\s*Name\s*:)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8HO1Gv/1).

**Details**

- `\bName` - a whole word `Name` (preceded with a word boundary `\b`)
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, that must be followed with...
- `(?=$|\s*Name\s*:)` - end of string (`$`) or 0+ whitespaces, `Name`, zero or more whitespaces and `:`.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/1SasxR):

```
x <- "Name :       O P Bansal                    Name :       Ganga Jawar              Name :     Ramachandran G."
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bName\\s*:\\s*\\K.*?(?=$|\\s*Name\\s*:)", x, perl=TRUE))
# => [[1]]
#   [1] "O P Bansal"      "Ganga Jawar"     "Ramachandran G."
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You are a life saver. Thanks

Comment: Just FYI: You may use almost the same expression with `stringr::str_match_all(x, "\\bName\\s*:\\s*(.*?)(?=$|\\s*Name\\s*:)")` and grab Column 2 (Group 1) values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Your names

```
list<- "Name :       O P Bansal                    Name :       Ganga Jawar              Name :     Ramachandran G."
```

Extract names ed remove initial and ending spaces

```
list_names<-trimws(unlist(strsplit(list,"Name :")))
list_names<-list_names[list_names!=""]
```

Your output

```
list_names
[1] "O P Bansal"      "Ganga Jawar"     "Ramachandran G."
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit`

```
trimws(strsplit(str1, "Name\\s*:\\s*")[[1]])[-1]
#[1] "O P Bansal"      "Ganga Jawar"     "Ramachandran G."
```

---

or with `gsub`

```
trimws(scan(text=gsub("\\s{2,}", ", ", gsub("Name\\s*:\\s*", "", str1)), what = "", sep=","))
#[1] "O P Bansal"      "Ganga Jawar"     "Ramachandran G."
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
str1 %>% 
   tibble(col = .) %>%
   separate_rows(col, sep = "Name\\s*\\:\\s*") %>% 
   filter(nzchar(col)) %>%
   mutate(col = trimws(col)) %>%
   pull(col)
#[1] "O P Bansal"      "Ganga Jawar"     "Ramachandran G."
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Name :       O P Bansal                    Name :       Ganga Jawar              Name :     Ramachandran G."
```